# Can process redirection be synchronised in bash?

Tags: c++, bash, process

I have the following C++ program compiled with `gcc -lstdc++ main.cpp -o main.out`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cerr << "Error 1" << endl;
    cout << "Ok "  << endl;
    cerr << "Wowza... that's bad..."  << endl;
    cerr << "Caused by X.";
    cout << "All good in the end." << endl;

    return 0;
};
```

I also have a bash script as follows, it's main purpose being to prefix STDOUT with "SUCCESS: " and STDERR with "ERROR: ".

```
./main.out > >(sed "s/^/SUCCESS: /g" >> main.log) 2> >(sed "s/^/ERROR  : /g" >> main.log)
```

If I `cat main.log` the result is:

```
ERROR  : Error 1
ERROR  : Wowza... that's bad...
ERROR  : Caused by X.
SUCCESS: Ok 
SUCCESS: All good in the end.
```

As you can see, the strings sent to STDERR all appear before the strings sent to STDOUT.

1. Why does the above occur? E.g., does bash evaluate all process substitutions from right to left?
2. Is there any way to synchronise these, so that the order of strings is that defined in the C++ example program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior that's vexing you is glibc's. In Linux, programs that link against glibc—which is pretty much all of them—[vary their output buffering mode](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_7.html#SEC118) based on where stdout and stderr are redirected. If they're connected to the TTY, they are line buffered. If they are redirected to a file, pipe, or other non-TTY device, glibc switches them to **fully buffered** mode. In fully buffered mode, output is flushed only every 4KB or so.

In your command-line, this affects both `main.out` and `sed`. `main.out`'s stdout and stderr are fully buffered when you add the `>` and `2>` redirections. The two `sed`s' stdout streams are fully buffered because they're redirected to `main.log`.

You can use `stdbuf` to override this behavior. `stdbuf` runs a command with input and output buffering of your choice. It works for most programs.

If you add `stdbuf` overrides to each of the three commands, you can get them to interleave their output. That's the good news.

```
$ rm main.log; stdbuf -oL -eL ./main.out > >(stdbuf -oL sed "s/^/SUCCESS: /g" >> main.log) 2> >(stdbuf -oL sed "s/^/ERROR  : /g" >> main.log); cat main.log
ERROR  : Error 1
ERROR  : Wowza... that's bad...
SUCCESS: Ok 
SUCCESS: All good in the end.
ERROR  : Caused by X.

$ rm main.log; stdbuf -oL -eL ./main.out > >(stdbuf -oL sed "s/^/SUCCESS: /g" >> main.log) 2> >(stdbuf -oL sed "s/^/ERROR  : /g" >> main.log); cat main.log
SUCCESS: Ok 
SUCCESS: All good in the end.
ERROR  : Error 1
ERROR  : Wowza... that's bad...
ERROR  : Caused by X.

$ rm main.log; stdbuf -oL -eL ./main.out > >(stdbuf -oL sed "s/^/SUCCESS: /g" >> main.log) 2> >(stdbuf -oL sed "s/^/ERROR  : /g" >> main.log); cat main.log
SUCCESS: Ok 
ERROR  : Error 1
SUCCESS: All good in the end.
ERROR  : Wowza... that's bad...
ERROR  : Caused by X.
```

The bad news is that the order of the lines is unpredictable. There is still no guarantee that the output will be in the order your program wrote it.

The reason is that fundamentally here you have a **race condition**. Your program and the two `sed` commands are three independent processes. There's no way to guarantee that they'll run in a certain order, that when your program spits out a line to stdout Linux will switch control to the appropriate `sed` process, then switch back to your program.

Linux could allow your program to write all of its output, then switch control to either `sed` process. It could interleave the two `sed` processes. It can perform context switches however it likes.

Not to mention, on a multi-core or multi-processor system the processes can run at the exact same time. It is a true race. Whichever `sed` runs fastest will output first.

To **synchronize** the processing you'll have to get rid of the multiple `sed` processes. Instead, have one process read from both streams. This is a more complicated design. You'll need two input descriptors, not just one. You'll need to somehow [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) and only read from them if there's input available. That kind of multiplexing takes some advanced shell scripting. You might be better of doing this in another language.

Comment: And the bad news is that the interleaving of lines is random (as demonstrated by your three examples with the same command but different output)?

Comment: @user1420752 Yep. Effectively random. Let me know if you want me to elaborate more on my last paragraph. It'll take me some time to whip up an example for that.

Comment: Can I just say... you are a legend. I consider myself reasonably skilled in Linux, but your answer is spot on. I wish there were a simpler way to accomplish what I want, e.g., if bash had the capability of alternating between processes with the `>()` syntax. I also tried `rm main.log; ./main.out > >(sed "s/^/$(date +%s.%N) SUCCESS: /g" >> main.log) 2> >(sed "s/^/$(date +%s.%N) ERROR  : /g" >> main.log); cat main.log ; sync ; sort -nk1 main.log` but the program executes so fast (or the timer resolution is so inaccurate) that each process redirection has only a single time value.

Comment: Re my previous comment, I didn't think it through - there's only a single time value because `$(date +%s.%N)` is evaluated only once.

Answer (score -1):

I can believe I can answer 1 myself by demonstration.

The process substitution occurs from right-to-left, as I assumed.

E.g., executing `./main.out 2> >(sed "s/^/ERROR  : /g" >> main.log) > >(sed "s/^/SUCCESS: /g" >> main.log) ; cat main.log` yields all the STDOUT messages before the STDERR messages:

```
SUCCESS: Ok 
SUCCESS: All good in the end.
ERROR  : Error 1
ERROR  : Wowza... that's bad...
ERROR  : Caused by X.
```